# Is it possible for a catch to get several exceptions?

Tags: c#, selenium, assert

I have a code similar to the one bellow:

```
           try { 

                SelectElement selectSize = new SelectElement(picProfileBtn);
                IList<IWebElement> optionsProfile = selectSize.Options;

                IWebElement firstProfile = optionsProfile[0];
                Assert.AreEqual("S", firstProfile.Text);
                IWebElement secondProfile = optionsProfile[1];
                Assert.AreEqual("M", secondProfile.Text);
                IWebElement thirdProfile = optionsProfile[2];
                Assert.AreEqual("L", thirdProfile.Text);
                IWebElement fourthProfile = optionsProfile[3];
                Assert.AreEqual("Test", fourthProfile.Text);
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

In case the first assert fails, is there a way to continue the test till the end? And if any other assert fails, or any other exception happens, It is all under the same stack trace message?

What I Have now, if one assert fails, the test exists and i get the message with the stack trace.

Comment: Is this some sort of homebrew test setup? It sounds like what you want is 4 separate tests rather than one test that does it all.

Comment: @HansKilian Yes, i have been writing this test setup. I am not doing small unit tests, but a bigger test that tests a part of a platform that is quite long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put each assert into it's own try/catch block like this.

```
       try { 

            SelectElement selectSize = new SelectElement(picProfileBtn);
            IList<IWebElement> optionsProfile = selectSize.Options;

            IWebElement firstProfile = optionsProfile[0];
            Assert.AreEqual("S", firstProfile.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        try {
            IWebElement secondProfile = optionsProfile[1];
            Assert.AreEqual("M", secondProfile.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        try {
            IWebElement thirdProfile = optionsProfile[2];
            Assert.AreEqual("L", thirdProfile.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        try {
            IWebElement fourthProfile = optionsProfile[3];
            Assert.AreEqual("Test", fourthProfile.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: This answers my question that one catch does not catch several exceptions and gives an alternative that works for me :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

you question is not completely clear, so I try to give it an interpretation.

Here is my suggestion, I hope is what you need:

```cs
try { 
    SelectElement selectSize = new SelectElement(picProfileBtn);
    IList<IWebElement> optionsProfile = selectSize.Options;

    try {
        IWebElement firstProfile = optionsProfile[0];
        Assert.AreEqual("S", firstProfile.Text);
    } catch(AssertFailedException e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Test 1 failed: " + ex.Message);
    }

    try {
        IWebElement secondProfile = optionsProfile[1];
        Assert.AreEqual("M", secondProfile.Text);
    } catch(AssertFailedException e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Test 2 failed: " + ex.Message);
    }

    try {
        IWebElement thirdProfile = optionsProfile[2];
        Assert.AreEqual("L", thirdProfile.Text);
    } catch(AssertFailedException e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Test 3 failed: " + ex.Message);
    }

    try {
        IWebElement fourthProfile = optionsProfile[3];
        Assert.AreEqual("Test", fourthProfile.Text);
    } catch(AssertFailedException e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Test 4 failed: " + ex.Message);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if not very clear. I was wondering if i can have several asserts and in case one fails, the test does not finish, but continues with the following asserts until the end of the test. In the end, all the exceptions are shown

Answer (score 0):

that is the concept of try catch, you should only write code which could lead to failure in try catch.

```
public void validate(string actual, string expected) {
try {
     Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected); }
catch (Exception ex){
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and call this method for all the verification like this :

```
 validate("S", optionsProfile[0]);
```

you can call this validate method as many times you want.

Comment: This is actually a great idea, i only saw this now. I will give it a go later for sure, thank you!

Comment: @DjNewma :This is more efficient then the one you have accepted since `Assert.AreEqual` is going to throw same exception every time.

Answer (score -1):

Use a for loop like this

```
           string[] profiles = { "S", "M", "L", "Test" };
            try
            {
                SelectElement selectSize = new SelectElement(picProfileBtn);
                IList<IWebElement> optionsProfile = selectSize.Options;
                for(int i = 0; i < profiles.Length; i++)
                {
                    IWebElement firstProfile = optionsProfile[i];
                    Assert.AreEqual(profiles[i], firstProfile.Text);
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: This is not legal C# code. Catch clause must to immediately follow the try block.